# Query show all event with the highest count (inner joins, subquery)

Tags: mysql

Here is the tables with the data inside. The problem I face is that
I want to show all the events with the date that has the maximum votes.

```
Event (id (PK), 
name, 
description, 
position_lat, 
position_lon, 
poll_close 
)

Event_date(
id (PK), 
Event_id (FK), 
Date
)

Vote (
Event_date_id (FK), 
user_id (FK)
)
```

Query:

```
SELECT ( 
SELECT COUNT(event_date_id) 
FROM vote 
WHERE vote.event_date_id = event_date.id) as votes, 
event.id,event.name, event.description, event.position_lat, event.position_lon, 
event.public_event, event_date.date 
FROM `event` 
INNER JOIN event_date ON event.id = event_date.event_id
```

when I execute the Query I get:

```
votes , id,  name , description .. Etc

3, 2 , Test Event, .. Etc

**1, 2 , Test Event, .. Etc**

0, 3, test2 Event, .. Etc
```

as you guys see I get the same event with id:2, two times because it has two requested dates that the event can be on. 
I want so show all the events once with the date that has the most votes, not the one in the middle that are marked with strong text.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please post text instead of image.

Comment: Eric: fixed text format.